# How to efficiently implement graph with a lot of big complete subgraphs?

Tags: c++, graph, boost-graph

I'm currently dealing with a performance issue of graph implementation.

### Used technologies

It is programmed in C++. For the moment, the graph is implemented thanks to the BGL.

### About the graph

The managed graph is dynamic and undirected. It has two kinds of structures: a lot of complete subgraphs and few of single edges. The only needed information is the direct neighborhood of a vertex.

### Problem statement

At the beginning, the complete subgraphs were small (about 10 vertices) and numerous (about 13k). An adjacency list implementation, the BGL's one, was perfect. But now, it is asked to manage few subgraph of 5000 vertices. That means 5000x5000 edges. The performance in time and space are then very poor now.

### Rejected solutions

My first thought was to use the adjacency matrix implementation provided by BGL. But it doesn't allow dynamic graph. To resolve this constraint, two solutions: provide a new implementation of adjacency matrix for dynamic graph or use a pool of available vertices in a static graph. After reflection, I think it's not a good idea: the space complexity is still VxV/2.

### Final Solution and question

So, here my final solution: don't use the BGL, implement bags of vertices to represent complete subgraphs (no need of edges) and directly connect vertices for the few single edges. By doing so, the space complexity of the biggest subgraph falls to its number of vertices, about 5000.

1. Do you think this last solution is the good one?
2. If not, which implementation could I use? And why?

#### Update 1

More information about the graph:
The graph has ~100k vertices, ~13k complete subgraphs of about 3 vertices, and ~100 complete subgraphs of size range [10-5000]. And each edge has bundled properties.

#### Update 2

I've recently learned thanks to [Salim Jouilli](http://www.loria.fr/~jouilisa/) that the bag of nodes is a candid approach of [hypergraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) where a hyperedge consists in a subset of nodes.

#### Update 3

I've finished to implement the solution. I've effectively gain in memory consumption and runtime: from 6GB to 24MB and from 50min to 2min30.

Comment: Next time, just answer the question (as an answer) and accept it. The accepted answer here is basically just a comment that agrees with you, which kind of breaks the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final solution is the one I would have gone for myself. It sounds as efficient as it can be.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem will scale up (again) in the future, maybe it is worth the effort of using a [graph database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database). This way you can decouple storage and business logic and treat them as separate problems.

Comment: But the program has to deal with the whole graph to compute the next states of each nodes. Is it possible to process complex queries with graph database?

Comment: I'm only familiar with http://neo4j.org/ . There, complex queries (like routing) are handled by the DB. If the included queries are not enough you can add your own queries via plugin. The idea is to communicate domain specific with the DB and therefore minimize DB queries that contain technical details. Have a look here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/index.html at the API. Then you can decide if it's overkill or suited for your problem.

Comment: Thanks. The URL about graph algorithms and how to implement yours is at http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-graph-algo/snapshot/index.html

Comment: I'll keep this solution for a future release. Currently, it is not an acceptable solution because of the chosen technologies, the deadline, and the customer specifications not finished.

Comment: If you managed to keep memory usage within MBs then the DB solution would have been overkill anyway. It's always nice to know what could be used when problems become unexpectedly big, though. :)

Comment: Thanks:). For the DB, you're right, it's overkilled for the moment. But it will be a good solution when the graph contains more nodes and has to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

Having 25M edges is no big deal in general. But I only used it on rather sparse graphs with lots of nodes also (a street network).

If the memory use and access time are getting critical for your need, try using boost compressed sparse graph http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/compressed_sparse_row.html

It's a bit annoying to use as it requires the edges to be inserted in an ordered way, but there is probably no way to be significantly more effective (by a very few percent at most).

Comment: I've checked the CSR and rejected it because of its unmutability: "While CSR graphs have much less overhead than many other graph formats (e.g., adjacency_list), they do not provide any mutability: one cannot add or remove vertices or edges from a CSR graph. Use this format in high-performance applications or for very large graphs that you do not need to change."